# How does one setup two non-load-balanced VM web servers in Azure, capable of communicating on private ports?

Tags: azure

I'd like to setup the below infrastructure in Azure. I have one possible solution, but it seems like it makes compromises in security architecture. Is there a better way to do this in Azure than in my compromised workaround?:

- **VM #1**:  Role: SQL Server and IIS. Server should have a unique public IP address. The hosted websites will be available through public port 80, and connect to local SQL Server.
- **VM #2**: Role: IIS. Server should have a unique public IP address. The hosted websites will be available through public port 80, and will connect to SQL Server on VM #1.

This has been my experience so far:

- No issues setting up VM #1.
- With VM #2, I tried building it in the same cloud service as VM #1. When I did that, it was assigned the same public IP address as VM #1. Thus, in this scenario, hosting websites on port 80 on both machines doesn't work.
- Next I tried building VM #2 in a different cloud service. This resulted in assignment of a unique public IP address. However, I was unable to obtain connectivity to SQL Server on VM #1.

  - Things I tried for the above: VM #1 SQL Server set as mixed mode, named SQL account provisioned (and connectivity confirmed locally), SQL configured to allow incoming remote TCP connections, firewall rule opened for incoming connections on TCP port that SQL runs under, but so far have not been able to connect to it from VM #2.

One architecture I believe would work is to open a public port on VM #1 and map that to the private SQL Server port. Then VM #2 could connect using the fully-qualifed public DNS name of VM #1. I believe Azure also would allow connectivity to be constrained to the public IP address of VM #2.

However, this seems less than ideal, because now SQL communication is being routed through a more public route than one would normally design for a data center, and an extra public port has to be opened on VM #1 (even if constrained by IP address, I'd rather not expose that surface area if not necessary). Additionally, sending the SQL Server data over a more public network hypothetically means transport security may need to be considered.

Research indicates connectivity between 2 VMs on different cloud services may not be possible using private ports, although the info I've found so far is not conclusive. So again, is there a better way to do this in Azure?

Comment: are you trying to load balance the web apps on both VMs? or are they separate apps?

Comment: These are separate apps--I do not want to load-balance them. One of the various reasons I'm aiming for this setup is to use traditional SSL (one cert per IP). Since there is no provision in Azure to assign more than one public IP address to a VM. SNI SSL was tried, but abandoned due to errors from pesky IE users on XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single cloud service is a security boundary and the only way into it is through a public (input) endpoint on the unique public VIP of the service. A Virtual Network (VNET) can be used to host multiple cloud services and allow private visibility among them without going through a public endpoint.

A typical model would be to put an IIS website in a PaaS cloud service with a public VIP and the backend SQL Server in an IaaS cloud service with a public VIP but NO public endpoints declared on it. Both these cloud services would be hosted in the same VNET. This allows the front end web role instances access to the backend SQL Server instance over the private VNET. There is a hands-on lab in the [Windows Azure Training Kit](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/other-resources/training-kit/) that describes precisely how to implement this.

In this case I would recommend separating the IIS/SQL Server combination so that the SQL Server box is in an IaaS cloud service with no public endpoint (although it will always have a public VIP). I would also recommend using either a Point-to-Site or Site-to-Site VPN which would allow you to access the VMs without exposing a public RDP endpoint. A point-to-site VPN is developer focused and very easy to configure. A site-to-site VPN is more of an IT thing since it requires configuration of a VPN router such as Cisco, Juniper or Windows Server.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I am digesting what you have pointed out here. 

* Just to confirm, there is no way to have 2 VMs on the same VNET, both hosting Internet-exposed websites on port 80, and each VM also having the ability to communicate with the other?

* For your suggestion on running standalone SQL Server as IAAS, and the websites as PAAS...sounds like in Azure, this means the SQL role is an Azure VM from image, and the websites are setup as PAAS Cloud Services (e.g. not PAAS Azure Websites)...correct?

* Thanks for the suggestions on securing RDP with VPN.

Comment: Each cloud service in a VNET gets its own public VIP and its own set of ports. Consequently, if you want to host two websites wit different VIPs then you host each of them in its own cloud service. However, rather than using an IaaS cloud service I recommend you look at Paas cloud service for website hosting. Windows Azure Websites cannot be added to a VNET so consequently cannot access a backend SQL Server instance without going through the public VIP.